# Embedded Mono: How to use 'mono_runtime_invoke' on different thread

Tags: c#, .net, mono, invoke, mono-embedding

Hi i'm using Embedded Mono with NaCl.  Everything is working so far but idk how to invoke a .NET method from c thats not on the same thread as the .NET exe was executed on.

Here is the method i'm trying to use:

```
void Mono_InvokeMethod(const char* assemblyName, const char* method, const char* arg)
{
    MonoAssemblyName* man = mono_assembly_name_new(assemblyName);
    assert(man);
    MonoAssembly* ma = mono_assembly_loaded(man);
    assert(ma);
    MonoImage* mi = mono_assembly_get_image(ma);
    assert(mi);
    MonoMethodDesc* mmd = mono_method_desc_new(method, "Second.Program" /* include_namespace */);
    assert(mmd);
    MonoMethod* mm = mono_method_desc_search_in_image(mmd, mi);
    assert(mm);
    void *args[1];
    args[0] = mono_string_new(mono_get_domain(), arg);//mono_get_root_domain() <<<<<<< Maybe use this instead

    mono_runtime_invoke(mm, NULL /* "this" object */, args, NULL /* exception */);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must start the new thread yourself and then call `mono_thread_attach` before `mono_runtime_invoke`. This is how it would look like, assuming `thread_callback` is called on a separate thread:

```
void thread_callback (MonoMethod *method, void **args)
{
    mono_thread_attach (mono_get_root_domain ());
    mono_runtime_invoke (method, NULL, args, NULL);
}
```

You can call `mono_thread_attach` as many times as you want, you don't have to keep track of whether you've called it for a particular thread or not.

Comment: Sry for the late response.  Right now its just hanging at 'mono_method_desc_search_in_image'... Never gets to 'mono_runtime_invoke'

Comment: @zezba9000: try debugging with gdb, that will tell you what the thread is trying to do. I believe there are locking requirements for some API (not sure about the ones you're using though), the mono source code should give you hints about this.

Comment: Im using mono in NaCl(Native Client) and I don't think I can run my project with debugging. I have to rely on runtime errors in the Chrome console window.  I'm sure yours is the correct answer, just am in the middle of getting some other pieces working. Tnx

Comment: Turns out I was calling the method wrong using '::' instead of ':' like so "MyNamespace.Program:TestMethod" It all works now :)